# cross_val_score() exits with Killed warning

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to do a study on how to improve the accuracy of some models, and I want to use a Bagging kNN with Cross_Evaluation. The code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

class MachineDataset():
    def __init__(self, data, X_train=None, y_train=None,
        X_test=None, y_test=None, clf=None):
        self.data = data
        self.X = self.data.loc[:, self.data.columns != data.columns[-1]]
        self.y = self.data[self.data.columns[-1]]
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.y_train = y_train
        self.X_test = X_test
        self.y_test = y_test
        self.clf = clf

    def set_clf(self, clf):
        self.clf = clf
   
    def eval_x_fold(self, x_fold=10): 
        eval_score = cross_val_score(self.clf, self.X, self.y, cv=x_fold)
        print("%0.2f accuracy" % eval_score.mean()*100)


def main():
    base_clf = KNeighborsClassifier(metric='minkowski', n_neighbors=5)
    clf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=base_clf,
                            n_estimators=500,
                            max_samples=1.0, max_features=1.0, bootstrap=False,
                            n_jobs=1, random_state=1)
    machine = MachineDataset(pd.read_csv('../Datasets/UJIIndoorLoc/UJIIndoorLoc_ID.csv'),
        clf=clf)
    machine.eval_x_fold()
    pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

however, when it runs, it shows something like:

```
Killed
```

I don't know what exactly is happening here, it may be a bad configuration?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means your script was killed by the OS. In most cases it's because it was using too much memory. Try looking at your memory usage during exectution.
You can use `cat /proc/meminfo` on Linux and Task Manager on Windows.

How big is the dataset?

If it is a memory problem, you will have to either get more RAM, use another computer with more RAM or reduce the size of the dataset.

Comment: Yes, I see it now... The dataset is not that big, however I see it is consuming a lot of resources. Thank you so much for your time!